# Cryptsetup "Warning" that shows up on boot

Tags: kubuntu, lvm, cryptsetup

I'm getting this warning every time my computer boots up and the encryption password screen shows up:

```
crytsetup: WARNING: cryptdata: Ignoring unknown option 'nofail'
```

Is there a way to disable it, or "fix" it?

My system uses Kubuntu 21.04 with the 5.11.0-25-generic kernel, and is encrypted (using lvm/crypt).

Thank you!

Comment: This option is most likely found in your `/etc/fstab` file for the encrypted volume. There is no harm in leaving it in place, as your system is simply ignoring the invalid option, but you *should* be able to remove it from `/etc/fstab` without any consequences.

Comment: might be best initially just to `#` the line out rather than remove it entirely until you're certain it is of no consequence.

Comment: Here is my `/etc/fstab` file. I don't see any option there.

`# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

UUID=xxx       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
UUID=xxx      /boot   ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=xxx  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-swap_1    none    swap    sw      0       0`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to remove the warning by deleting nofail from

```
/etc/crypttab
```

and then running

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just commenting out that WARNING line in here:

```
/usr/lib/cryptsetup/functions
```

Then ran:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Not the best solution, but the only one that works so far.